# Creating Modules with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am working with PyCharm and am trying to create a module from code I've created so that I can import it into new files.  In IntelliJ you can start the module creator but in PyCharm this option does not seem to exist.

Without a module when I type:

```
import my_code
```

I receive a warning saying "No module named my_code".

I've tried creating packages to replace the module but this does not work.

How do you repackage code in PyCharm so you can import it into a new file?

The project structure is quite simple.  I have a number of files I've created as part of a tutorial.  I want to make one of the files, "Importing_Files" a module so that I can import it into another file, i.e., "Import_Tester".  I've added a picture below to show the tree.

[image]

Comment: Please describe your project structure

Comment: @user2235698 I've edited the post to show the project structure and have provided a brief explanation.  Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: You could try to move files out of `HelloWorld` folder or mark `HelloWorld` folder as source root

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would suggest.  It looks like you've already tried to set things up correctly, but you need to organize things in Pycharm a bit differently.  I ran into a similar problem, which is why I think having an answer to this question is useful.

Your .idea directory is within the package, which makes things awkward.  Try this:

1. Create a new Pycharm project based on the top level of the project.
2. Make src and test directories within that project, and set them as source root and test root, respectively.
3. Move the HelloWorld package into src (make sure it's still recognized as a package).
4. Create new files in src with main sections for any functions you need to run from the command line, add imports for your package, and move your **main** code into it.
5. For any **main** functions that define tests, do the same thing -- create files with **main** logic in the tests directory.  Unit tests are a better way to do that, but this directory structure should work.
6. Remove the old project (delete the .idea directory in HelloWorld).

The final project layout should look something like this:

```
 CompletePythonMasterClassUdemy
     .idea
     src
         command_line_main.py
         HelloWorld
             __init__.py
             ...
     test
         test_account.py
```

This is a better way to organize things that should work both within and outside of Pycharm.  Unlike the Java world, Python doesn't have as many common conventions for correctly setting up projects.  There are very likely better ways to do things, but this works well for me. It should work well for people getting started with Python library development.